# assert doesn't work when raised in class instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, assert

`assert` doesn't raise an exception when called in an instance of a class:

```
class TestCaseTest(TestCase):
    ...
    def testFailedResutFormatted(self):
        ...
        assert False    # This doesn't work at all

TestCaseTest("testFailedResutFormatted").run()
assert False    # But this works just fine
```

Full code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/Hc9CTTxH

I am obviously doing something wrong, because these are examples from the book and they should work. I just can't figure out what is the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assert False` works *just fine*, but the `AssertionError` is caught by the `TestCase.run()` method, to be collected later.

You didn't pass in a `TestResult` instance, so in Python 3 the `TestCase.run()` function returns a *new* result object for you:

```
>>> from unittest import TestCase
>>> class TestCaseTest(TestCase):
...     def testFailedResutFormatted(self):
...         assert False
...
>>> tc = TestCaseTest("testFailedResutFormatted")
>>> tc.run()
<unittest.result.TestResult run=1 errors=0 failures=1>
```

There you see a failure has been recorded.

Pass in a `TestResult` instance to the `TestCase.run()` method and it'll be used instead; the `result.failures` attribute shows the assertion fired and was recorded:

```
>>> from unittest import TestResult
>>> result = TestResult()
>>> tc.run(result)
>>> result
<unittest.result.TestResult run=1 errors=0 failures=1>
>>> result.failures
[(<__main__.TestCaseTest testMethod=testFailedResutFormatted>, 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<stdin>", line 3, in testFailedResutFormatted\nAssertionError\n')]
>>> print result.failures[0][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in testFailedResutFormatted
AssertionError
```